# How to query a date field for a specific month with Postges and Knex.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js, objection.js

Im setting up a new date query using Knex.js and Postgres. I need to return all the rows for a specific month from the table.

This is for a simple app API. Ive managed to return all the fields from the table that I want but don't know how to query the date field for the specific month. Im using Knex.js as my query builder and have the following:

```
db('table').select() 
.where('Month(date)', '=', 0  ); //this field where I am lost,
```

the sql I think will do the job is: `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dateColumn::date) = 1`

I get an error at the moment. But I am expecting to query to return all the date fields that are in the month of January. I know that I could use the `.whereRaw()` field but Im not 100% sure how to use this either as the documentation does not provide any use cases for date fields.

For reference the column `date` that I want to query is of format `date`

Comment: If you can add an example what kind of SQL query you like to produce it would be easier to give an exact knex equivalent for it.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get this to work by using the `.whereRaw()` API of knex.

```
.andWhereRaw(`EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dateColumn::date) = ?`, [monthVariable])
```

Im not totally sure why, but it only worked with the `::date` suffix to my `dateColumn`. This will cast my dateColumn to postgres dateType. The confusing part is that the `dateColumn` was already of type `date`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
db('table').where(db.raw('EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ??::date)', ['dateColumn']), 0)
```

Comment: Didn't have any luck with this. I got the message "global knex.raw is deprecated".

Comment: Right.. you had created knex instance with name `db`. Fixed the answer.

Comment: Also updated answer to match the updated query in the question.